# javascript array format via for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

What I am doing wrong here? I am getting `TypeError: items[i] is undefined` as the error.

```
var items = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    items[i].push('a', 'b', 'c');
}
console.log(items);
```

I need an output as given below,

```
[
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the following:

```
items.push(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

No need to access the array using the index, just push another array in.

The `.push()` method will automatically add it to the *end* of the array.

```
var items = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    items.push(['a', 'b', 'c']);
}
console.log(items);
```

As a side note, it's worth pointing out that the following would have worked:

```
var items = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    items[i] = []; // Define the array so that you aren't pushing to an undefined object.
    items[i].push('a', 'b', 'c');
}
console.log(items);
```

Comment: Ok, that solved my problem! Can you explain why it is reporting that error? I mean what's wrong with my code?

Comment: @DipendraGurung The `.push()` method will automatically append the items to the end of the array. On each iteration, you were trying to access a value that *didn't* exist in the array. See the update.

Comment: You are trying to access 'items[i]' which is undefined as array is empty.